# stopping auto rotation of my site on smartphones

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a smartphone interface on my site in CF and javascript. It seems to work great on the smartphones I have tested. The problem is that it is a vertical alignment with horizontal images rotated 90 deg ccw and so the site has some photos that the phone must be turned cw to maintain image size and proportions.

I used this code to get the browser size and create the site to fit:

```
window.location.href = "1.cfm?Wth=" + size.width + + size.height + "";
```

Is there any way I can instruct either the phone or browser not to auto rotate? Preferrably with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable auto rotation on smartphone browser.
And even if you could, you should not. It's not user-friendly.

But if you really want, there is a dirty hack that involves returning the entire page to the rotation event : [Blocking device rotation on mobile web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages).

If it's only an image size problem, resize your images when a rotation screen event is triggered.

Comment: guess ur right Damian. Just ask visitors to turn off auto rotate but so few seem to even know how to do this. give them a picture of the little icon i guess...


as far as re-sizing images. it really would make the horizontal ones small and they would look lost in the window.

Comment: Yes ask visitors to turn off the auto rotate is impossible, they don't know how to do this and it's a really bad practice. I think you have to redesign your interface.Usually a responsive design with CSS values in percent ​​and some media queries do the job.