# How do I lock the orientation to portrait mode in a Mobile Web Application?

Tags: javascript, html, web, portrait

I am making a web application using html, and javascript for mobile devices (phones). How can I lock the screen orientation in portrait? Are there any extensions, or frameworks to do this?

EDIT: 
When the user goes into landscape mode, I want a only a div (in the shape of a box if it matters) to be displayed that contains the text "please turn your device to portrait."

Comment: take a look at this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages

Comment: There is event to detect `orientationChange`.  However locking the screen resolution is not a right option for a responsive website.  Better handle it

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like the following CSS media query:

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
   .main-content { display: none; }
   .use-portrait { display: block; }
}
```

Which would hide your `main-content` and show the `use-portrait` div when the device is in landscape mode. You can use some additional CSS to rotate the `use-portrait` div to further entice the user to do that:

```
.use-portrait {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);    
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
}
```

And you may need to translate it to appear correctly.

Comment: do you know if IE supports it?

Comment: great solution. i used it to show a html-message "please use portrait mode" without any changes at my canvas (pixi.js). thx!

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
 event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. Where would you recommend putting it.

Comment: This event exists in jQuery mobile and catches the same event as the CSS equivalent, so you can use it, but there is no valid `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.preventDefault()` which would make this work. You still need to write a custom solution, for which you can use the value of `event.orientation`.