# How do I lock the screen orientation to portrait in Safari using plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, safari, mobile-safari

I want to "lock" the orientation of the website to portrait mode in [safari](/questions/tagged/safari) using pure javascript.

Let's say that I am building an application, I don't want users to be able to visit my app in landscape-mode. How do I do that?

---

**Edit:** I make the app in web-languages, I will assign it as a profile so anyone can download it on iPhone, so nothing with xCode or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blocking device rotation on mobile web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages)

Comment: Yeah well that did not work, and I require JavaScript only

Comment: Everything under **Edit 2** is pure javascript.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to explain what happened in language more descriptive than "did not work".

Comment: It gave me 2-3 errors, I'm not with my computer at the moment but I will give them tomorow.

Answer (score 1):

the [screen.lockOrientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation) method is not supported by Safari, so you'll have to do feature detection.

For Safari, you might try the ponyfill: https://github.com/chmanie/o9n

Answer (score 0):

maybe using "windows.screen" work for you;

```
var alowed = window.screen.orientation.lock("portrait");
```