# Blocked JS deviceorientation devicemotion on Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webview, android-sensors

I've written a JS SDK for Android WebView that collects device orientation and motion. The SDK listens to `deviceorientation` and `devicemotion` events on the window like so:

```
window.addEventListener('devicemotion', (event) => {...})
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (event) => {...})
```

On some devices/integrations, I get no sensors data. I've tried to mimic a "bad" integration, attempting to block the WebView sensors access by adding the following to the app manifest but with no luck. The JS events are still triggered:

```
<activity
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

What are other possible ways to block the WebView from triggering the events, besides disabling JS all together?

**Update:**
Some insights:
the most problematic devices are:

- Samsung Galaxy Tab a 10.1 SM-T580
- Samsung Galaxy J5 Prime SM-G570M

**Update 2**
I have similar issues on IOS on some devices, most problematic is:

- Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X)
  AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148

Comment: can you inject js?

Comment: No, it should be done in the native layer.

Comment: did you tried android version?

Comment: [Blocking device rotation on mobile web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Might be, it's not possible to stop only triggering JS events through android, if you want it then it'll disable whole JS.

```
//disabled
  wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
//enabled
  wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

As, you told that on some devices you aren't getting sensors data, for this you need to check your webview decleration code. 
Sample code is here:

```
  wView= new WebView(this);
  wView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
  wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  wView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

  wView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
            // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
            onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
        }
    });

  wView.loadUrl(HOST_URL);
```

**In Manifest**

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have no control over the webview declaration. js is not disabled since I'm getting other params from my SDK. Just sensor data is disabled for some reason. My goal is to understand why and to try to mimic the behavior locally.

Comment: can i get that web url?

Comment: Just create a simple HTML page with `window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (event) => {...})` and see if you can disable it from being triggered using native code. thanks :)

Comment: what's your working platform? Android(native) or Ionic

Comment: and what you want like you want to catch trigger JS functions in android?

Comment: and what you're using 'deviceorientation' or 'orientationchange'

Comment: Android native with a webView, the JS already catch other events like touchStart. it fails to detect `deviceorientation` and `devicemotion` events