# Disable landscape view for a responsive design website

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, landscape

How to let my website not be used in landscape?

I tried this and didnt work

`<meta http-equiv="ScreenOrientation" content="autoRotate:disabled">`

I am using media queries for varying width.

Comment: What do you mean "disable landscape"... do you mean you want to prevent the user from changing the orientation of the web page if they want to rotate their device? That sounds like a pretty poor user experience - if you want people to user your website, you try to let them do what they want instead of forcing them to do something they don't want and make them leave.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blocking device rotation on mobile web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried which doesn't work.
<meta http-equiv="ScreenOrientation" content="autoRotate:disabled" />